# Getting domain variables on layout

Tags: layout, grails

What is the best way to pass the model variables to layout in Grails? Specifically, I'm using Spring security plugin which has User class. I also have Contact class that looks like this:

```
class Contact {

    String realname
    String company
    String mobile
    String fix
    String email
    User user
        ...
```

What are the options for getting the currently logged in person's company in my layout (main.gsp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the above answer, you could alternatively set a session variable for the user when you login in whatever controller method gets called.

You can also just set a session variable for the company in the controller method:

```
session.company = Contact.findByUser(session.user)?.company
```

or from the example above

```
   session.company = Contact.findByUser(SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication?.principal)?.company
```

And in your main.gsp, something like:

```
<span id="companyName">${session.company}</span>
```

Comment: At this case you should implement your own authSuccesshandler and logoutHandler, and put (and remove on logout) this variable into a session there, not at controller

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you need to pass this model for every page, automatically, instead of manual passing it at render at each of controllers? You can use [filters](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6%20Filters) there:

```
def filters = {
    all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
            request.setAttribute('loggedInPerson', SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication?.principal)
            //Notice, that there is used original Authentication, from Spring Security
            //If you need you can load your Contact object there, or something
        }
        after = {

        }
        afterView = {

        }
    }
}
```

and use `loggedInPerson` at your gsp:

```
Hello ${loggedInPerson.username}!
```

Btw, there is also [Spring Security tags](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib), that can help you without using your own filter, like:

```
Hello <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username"/>!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a certain object to the model, you can also use the "interceptors" provided by grails. To add a certain variable to a particular controller, you can use something like this.

```
def afterInterceptor = {model, modelAndView->

    model.loggedInUser = getLoggedInUser()  // retrieve your user details here

}
```

And you can retrieve `loggedInUser` in the main.gsp layout as `${loggedInUser}`.

If you need to get these details in multiple controllers, you can create a `BaseController` and keep the `afterInterceptor` in this `BaseController`. All controllers which need the reference to the logged in user in their corresponding views should extend the `BaseController`.